# Formula Time * Currency giving strange outcome

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I am trying to calculate total wage in a google-spreadsheet by the following formula:

> worked hours * hourly rate

However this is giving very strange outcomes, please note the F colum in [this example document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M-v2EjXHCOVS6VJskqS98MfGxS9geNVi8Flp49Nbl6E/edit#gid=0).

Does anyone know the right way to write this formula? 
(I am using euros as currency, i don't think this should matter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time is internally stored as decimal number from 0 to 1, where 1 means 24 hours,
thus 2 hours(or 2:00 AM) equals 0.08333... (= 2 / 24)
So, the calculation result is correct: 35 * 0.08333... = 2.91666...

To extract hour from the number, you can use the function `HOUR`, like this:

```
=E4 * HOUR(D4)
```